# Book about a kid from London who ends up having to trade technology from other times and worlds (I think)

Tags: story-identification

#### Key Plot points

1. It's about a kid who gets recruited to travel through different times and realities having to trade technology for new tech.
2. I remember there's a rival between 2 clans.
3. I think the clans originally started from brothers.

This is all I can remember.

#### Chronology and other relevant info

I read this book a long time ago. I think the cover has a snake on it.

Comment: How long is "long time ago"? Please provide the year even if you have to provide a range e.g. 1980-1989

Comment: Was it a children's book, or a book aimed at young adults, or a book for adults?